# Sum a IQueryable Column with where clause

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 queries. One to find where Value column is greater than 150,000 and i need the count of entries. The second one is the sum of that rather than count.
The Count works perfectly but the sum crashes and provides this error

> {"The cast to value type 'System.Decimal' failed because the
>   materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter
>   or the query must use a nullable type."}

Working code:

```
var excessCount = closedDealNonHost.Any() ? closedDealNonHost.Where(x => x.Value > 150000).Count()  : 0;
```

Crashing Code:

```
var excessSum = CloseDealNonHost = closedDealNonHost.Any() ? closedDealNonHost.Where(x => x.Value > 150000).Sum(x => x.Value) : 0;
```

Comment: Some of your data has `NULL` values in them. You need to handle the `NULL` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the issue by explicitly casting to `decimal?` in `Sum` like:

```
var excessSum = CloseDealNonHost = closedDealNonHost.Any() ? closedDealNonHost
                                  .Where(x => x.Value > 150000)
                                  .Sum(x => (decimal?) x.Value) : 0;
```

The issue is due to generated SQL from LINQ expression, and at C# end it will try to return `decimal` which can't accommodate a `null` value, hence the error.

You may see: [Linq To Entities: Queryable.Sum returns Null on an empty list](https://ilmatte.wordpress.com/2012/12/20/queryable-sum-on-decimal-and-null-return-value-with-linq-to-entities/)

Comment: Thanks Habib for the informative answer. It worked perfectly and now I have a clear understanding of the problem =)