# Linq count nulls as in SQL

Tags: sql, linq, count, null

I'm trying to convert the following sql to linq

```
select 
  sum(case when answer is null then 1 else 0 end) as numAnaswered 
from questions
where id =@id
```

Seems easy with linq Count, but it gives 0 when id is not in the table. While the sql above returns null

What is the most simple LINQ that does the trick?

Comment: Are you using EF?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
var numAnaswered= db.Questions.Where(q=>q.Id== id).Sum(q=>q.answer==null?(int?)1:0);
```

Comment: What's the difference? The result is still 0 for empty input sequence.

Comment: Lol :) Anyway, the only way to make this work is to hit the `int?` overload of `Sum`, by using `? (int?1 : 0)` for instance. It would work with L2E, L2O is broken and will return always 0 (there was a SO question regarding that strange behavior).

Comment: Right, I got your point, let me fix it, thanks ;), but to return `null` the condition would not be `q.answer==null?(int?)1:null` ?

Comment: No if you want to simulate the exact SQL query result. SQL `SUM` returns `NULL` only if there are no records matching the `WHERE` clause. While `CASE WHEN` should be directly translated to `? : `.

Comment: mmm, I didn't know that, thanks again, you're an mvp on this ;)

Comment: thanks guys. Intial tests show that ? (int?1 : 0) does the trick, while (int?)1:null does null also when 0 answers

Comment: Yes, I was checking old questions with the same problem, like this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29257092/sum-a-iqueryable-column-with-where-clause